# How To Use Single Snackbar And Turn Into Multi Snackbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, toast, snackbar

I found this cool `snackbar` which I can use on my test website for learning reasons.

```
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_snackbar
```

This `snackbar` uses ID so I will have to copy paste `CSS` as well as `javascript` over and over. if I want 4 different `snackbar` on same page than I will have to copy paste `CSS` code 4 times... that can be annoying.

So here is my attempt of setting multi `snackbar`. you can copy paste my code in above link to see the results.

As you can see, the effect works but it loses the `CSS` code. Any idea?

again: In `snackbar` id... I'm just creating layout of box, so I can change `snackbar` to class... and have id for unique box.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    .snackbar {
        visibility: hidden;
        min-width: 250px;
        margin-left: -125px;
        background-color: #333;
        color: #fff;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 2px;
        padding: 16px;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 1;
        left: 50%;
        bottom: 30px;
        font-size: 17px;
    }

    .snackbar.show {
        visibility: visible;
        -webkit-animation: fadein 0.5s, fadeout 0.5s 2.5s;
        animation: fadein 0.5s, fadeout 0.5s 2.5s;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes fadein {
        from {bottom: 0; opacity: 0;} 
        to {bottom: 30px; opacity: 1;}
    }

    @keyframes fadein {
        from {bottom: 0; opacity: 0;}
        to {bottom: 30px; opacity: 1;}
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes fadeout {
        from {bottom: 30px; opacity: 1;}
        to {bottom: 0; opacity: 0;}
    }

    @keyframes fadeout {
        from {bottom: 30px; opacity: 1;}
        to {bottom: 0; opacity: 0;}
    }

</style>
</head>

<body>

    <h2>Snackbar / Toast</h2>
    <p>Snackbars are often used as a tooltips/popups to show a message at the bottom of the screen.</p>
    <p>Click on the button to show the snackbar. It will disappear after 3 seconds.</p>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Show Snackbar</button>

    <div id="myUniqueBar" class="snackbar">Some text some message..</div>

    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var x = document.getElementById("myUniqueBar")
            x.className = "show";
            setTimeout(function(){ x.className = x.className.replace("show", ""); }, 3000);
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you need to copy-paste your CSS? You already are using classes...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple snackbars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34465005/android-multiple-snackbars-in-separate-fragments-viewpager)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are removing your existing snackbar class when using the code:

`x.className = "show";`

Instead replace the above code with this code:

```
x.classList.add("show");
```

**Codepen link:** https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KZRJmP